# Python3 OpenCV - LIBTDB ERROR: data is not tagged properly

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I'm getting this error by running this python script (converted into .exe) I found on github on my Acer Tablet with Windows 8.1:
LIBTDB ERROR: data is not tagged properly

(the script continues after printing the error)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import struct
from io import BytesIO
IP = '192.168.1.8'

# Capture frame
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) ## here the error

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect((IP, 8080))

while cap.isOpened():
    _, frame = cap.read()

    memfile = BytesIO()
    np.save(memfile, frame)
    memfile.seek(0)
    data = memfile.read()

    # Send form byte array: frame size + frame content
    client_socket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data)) + data)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
```

It works fine on my windows 10 pc, but I wanted to try it on two different devices.

Comment: please include the error in your post

Comment: Hey, please install Windows SDK 8.1 cause it includes directshow headers, libraries, SDK tools, and samples. It solves the problem for me.